# How do I fill out dates until end of year with last value column repeated for filled dates in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is a reproducible example

```
name <- c("A","B","B","C","C","C")
date <- c('2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-01-01','2024-02-01','2024-03-01')
value<- c("1.0","1.2","1.2","0.6","0.6","0.6")
 count <- c("1","1","2","1","2","3")
df <- data.frame(name,date,value,count)

df %>% group_by(name)%>%
    mutate(scalingvalue = cumsum(as.numeric(value) / n()))

name       date value count  scalingvalue
 A  2024-01-01   1.0     1     1
 B  2024-01-01   1.2     1     0.6
 B  2024-02-01   1.2     2     1.2
 C  2024-01-01   0.6     1     0.2
 C  2024-02-01   0.6     2     0.4
 C  2024-03-01   0.6     3     0.6
```

This is what the end goal is (only showing C, but I want it for each name) I'd like the dates to be filled out to the end of the year or maybe until 2025 (date not already existing) The "scalingvalue" of each new generated date should be the latest pre-existing date's "scalingvalue" repeated.

```
name       date value count  scalingvalue
 A  2024-01-01   1.0     1     1
 B  2024-01-01   1.2     1     0.6
 B  2024-02-01   1.2     2     1.2
 C  2024-01-01   0.6     1     0.2
 C  2024-02-01   0.6     2     0.4
 C  2024-03-01   0.6     3     0.6
 C  2024-04-01   0.6     3     0.6
 C  2024-05-01   0.6     3     0.6
 C  2024-06-01   0.6     3     0.6
 C  2024-07-01   0.6     3     0.6
 C  2024-08-01   0.6     3     0.6
 C  2024-09-01   0.6     3     0.6
 C  2024-10-01   0.6     3     0.6
 C  2024-11-01   0.6     3     0.6
 C  2024-12-01   0.6     3     0.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of `complete` (with `seq.Date`) and `fill`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         scalingvalue = cumsum(as.numeric(value) / n())) %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(min(date), as.Date("2024-12-01"), by = "month")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  fill(name, value, count, scalingvalue)
```

Output

```
# name     date       value count scalingvalue
# <chr>    <date>     <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#  1 A     2024-01-01 1.0   1              1  
#  2 A     2024-02-01 1.0   1              1  
#  3 A     2024-03-01 1.0   1              1  
#  4 A     2024-04-01 1.0   1              1  
#  5 A     2024-05-01 1.0   1              1  
#  6 A     2024-06-01 1.0   1              1  
#  7 A     2024-07-01 1.0   1              1  
#  8 A     2024-08-01 1.0   1              1  
#  9 A     2024-09-01 1.0   1              1  
# 10 A     2024-10-01 1.0   1              1  
# 11 A     2024-11-01 1.0   1              1  
# 12 A     2024-12-01 1.0   1              1  
# 13 B     2024-01-01 1.2   1              0.6
# 14 B     2024-02-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 15 B     2024-03-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 16 B     2024-04-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 17 B     2024-05-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 18 B     2024-06-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 19 B     2024-07-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 20 B     2024-08-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 21 B     2024-09-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 22 B     2024-10-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 23 B     2024-11-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 24 B     2024-12-01 1.2   2              1.2
# 25 C     2024-01-01 0.6   1              0.2
# 26 C     2024-02-01 0.6   2              0.4
# 27 C     2024-03-01 0.6   3              0.6
# 28 C     2024-04-01 0.6   3              0.6
# 29 C     2024-05-01 0.6   3              0.6
# 30 C     2024-06-01 0.6   3              0.6
# 31 C     2024-07-01 0.6   3              0.6
# 32 C     2024-08-01 0.6   3              0.6
# 33 C     2024-09-01 0.6   3              0.6
# 34 C     2024-10-01 0.6   3              0.6
# 35 C     2024-11-01 0.6   3              0.6
# 36 C     2024-12-01 0.6   3              0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively please try the below approach where we dont have to use the date `2024-12-01`

```r
# get the max date by month 12
end_date <- df |> group_by(name) |> slice_tail(n=1) |> 
  mutate(end_date= as.Date(paste(year(date),max(month(date),12),day(date), sep = '-')))

# expand the date by seq
df2 <- end_date |> mutate(date=as.Date(date)) |> rowwise() |>
mutate(date=list(seq(as.Date(date)+ months(1), end_date, by='month'))) |> 
  unnest(cols = date) %>% select(-end_date)

# combine the data frames
df <- rbind(df,df2 |> mutate(date=as.character(date))) %>% arrange(name, date)


# output
   name       date value count
1     A 2024-01-01   1.0     1
2     A 2024-02-01   1.0     1
3     A 2024-03-01   1.0     1
4     A 2024-04-01   1.0     1
5     A 2024-05-01   1.0     1
6     A 2024-06-01   1.0     1
7     A 2024-07-01   1.0     1
8     A 2024-08-01   1.0     1
9     A 2024-09-01   1.0     1
10    A 2024-10-01   1.0     1
11    A 2024-11-01   1.0     1
12    A 2024-12-01   1.0     1
13    B 2024-01-01   1.2     1
14    B 2024-02-01   1.2     2
15    B 2024-03-01   1.2     2
16    B 2024-04-01   1.2     2
17    B 2024-05-01   1.2     2
18    B 2024-06-01   1.2     2
19    B 2024-07-01   1.2     2
20    B 2024-08-01   1.2     2
21    B 2024-09-01   1.2     2
22    B 2024-10-01   1.2     2
23    B 2024-11-01   1.2     2
24    B 2024-12-01   1.2     2
25    C 2024-01-01   0.6     1
26    C 2024-02-01   0.6     2
27    C 2024-03-01   0.6     3
28    C 2024-04-01   0.6     3
29    C 2024-05-01   0.6     3
30    C 2024-06-01   0.6     3
31    C 2024-07-01   0.6     3
32    C 2024-08-01   0.6     3
33    C 2024-09-01   0.6     3
34    C 2024-10-01   0.6     3
35    C 2024-11-01   0.6     3
36    C 2024-12-01   0.6     3
```